# IOC variable resolution PHP

Tags: php, oop, inversion-of-control, slim

This is a snippet from the Slim framework. I am trying to understand how the $c value is set. I did an error_log() and it's a type Slim\Helper\Set which is a singleton

```
public function __construct(array $userSettings = array())
{
    // Setup IoC container
    $this->container = new \Slim\Helper\Set();
    $this->container['settings'] = array_merge(static::getDefaultSettings(), $userSettings);

    // Default environment
    $this->container->singleton('environment', function ($c) {
        return \Slim\Environment::getInstance();
    });

    // Default request
    $this->container->singleton('request', function ($c) {
        return new \Slim\Http\Request($c['environment']);
    });
    .... snip
```

}

I have seen a similar example in the Pimple website http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/

```
// define some services
$container['session_storage'] = function ($c) {
    return new SessionStorage('SESSION_ID');
};

$container['session'] = function ($c) {
    return new Session($c['session_storage']);
};
```

How does $c get set ? It's not a global variable.

Thanks
K

Answer (score 0):

Let's dissect this

```
$this->container->singleton('environment', function ($c) {
    return \Slim\Environment::getInstance();
});
```

They're passing two arguments. The first is the string `environment` which probably instructs the function as to what type of class to instantiate (my guess is bolstered by [this class](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/faf83069298593bdfd8482a14bda171937473fc1/Slim/Environment.php)). The second argument (where `$c` is) is an anonymous function.

Based on what `Slim\Set` [looks like](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/faf83069298593bdfd8482a14bda171937473fc1/Slim/Helper/Set.php#L222)

```
/**
 * Ensure a value or object will remain globally unique
 * @param  string   $key   The value or object name
 * @param  \Closure $value The closure that defines the object
 * @return mixed
 */    
public function singleton($key, $value)
{
    $this->set($key, function ($c) use ($value) {
        static $object;
        if (null === $object) {
            $object = $value($c);
        }
        return $object;
    });
}
```

So you're calling this function. `$value` is a callable (function). You can see where `$c` is set in this line

```
$object = $value($c);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Slim and Pimple, the $c parameter is the Pimple container object.